# 404 Admin Error

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error

I am new to WordPress and was looking at settings in the admin. I believe I changed the directory of the site from `example.com/wp/` to `example.com`. When I saved the changes I immediately saw a 404 error that says:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

In trying to fix what I messed up I came across [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52573/54881) which an answer said to `Delete .htaccess` however I believe the root cause in that question is different than my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to open up `phpMyAdmin` open up the database then open up `wp_options`. From there I had to change the `siteurl` and add `/wp` to the end and it works again.

Comment: Better and easier way you should've done is Update permalinks..