# Getting "404 page not found" error when i access to my Login page

Tags: 404-error

I am getting the 404 error when I enter wp-admin after my domain.I am using infinity free hosting and getting this page https://infinityfree.net/errors/404/
when I access my WordPress login page. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52573/im-getting-a-404-message-when-i-try-to-access-wpadmin), or try solutions to [these](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp-admin+404) questions.